# URL WCF RestFul .net with spring

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, spring.net, wcf-rest

I need to call my service with the standard url restful:

```
http://localhost/users : getall user
http://localhost/user/1 : get user with id 1
```

But the standard URLs in WCF looks like:

```
http://localhost/Userservice.svc/getallusers
```

I would like to change this, but since I use the Spring.net framework in my service WCF, I must create my Custom ServiceHostFactory MyServiceHostFactory

Spring is used in my project to do the injection dependencies and thus nothing new object

I try to add a route in global.asax

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Users", new MyServiceHostFactory(), typeof(UserService)));
```

But when i call my service http://localhost/users
, I receive the error: `ServiceHost only supports class service types`

I don't understand the problem and is it possible to resolve this problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a setting that you need to change on the server level.  If you're serving it through the IIS localhost, you'll need to change the settings on the local IIS to allow extensionless URLs.  First make sure that this update has been applied: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368?wa=wsignin1.0  Additional instructions are included in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4.aspx

Comment: I work with IIS 8.5 in Windows 8 and thus I don't found the version qfe for this os and in my iis the Handler mapping is always configured ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit was already enabled. what do I have to do precisely to work ?

Comment: Have you considered the URL Rewrite module?  I couldn't recommend it until I knew what version of IIS you were in.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Dec/15/Removing-the-SVC-Extension-from-WCF-REST-URLs